# AWS IOT Core - How to have a thermostat to mimic the historical temperature of another room?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, iot

I'm currently building a project where I'm trying to make the thermostat of this room (say, Room A), follow the past temperature (with a certain delay) of Room B. I am currently collecting the temperatures of both Room A and Room B to store them in a DynamoDB table after recording the temperature every 1 minute (give or take a few seconds). This is done through ESP32 to AWS IOT Core to DynamoDB.

I'm trying to design a system where I can have the user input the time delay, and the room name. For which, I want the temperature of the target room to closely follow the temperature of another room by the use of a periodic MQTT message to the device to change its temperature.

ie. The user wants the temperature of room A to be the same as the temperature of room B 2 hours prior. With a given start time of 2PM and the target time of 12PM, AWS IOT Core should ping the ESP32 to change its temperature relative to the temperature 2 hours prior.

I have used a Lambda function to do so currently. ESP32 will send an MQTT message to IOT Core for an update, and a Lambda will be triggered, where we search for the temperature data point that corresponds to the relative time and send it back to the device to update. However, this is very inefficient and ideally AWS should be the one to trigger the update at the specific time.

Key issue is also, because we want an accurate temperature delta, we cannot have a fixed time interval.